# I need help structuring my data in my SwiftUI application. I have a mutating func in my struct but the "if let" mutates the copy and not original

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, concurrency

I'm building a SwiftUI application and one of my Models has a mutating func that's purpose is to help update the UI when changes occur. For example, if a user updates their username I want to just call the mutating func to update the Model and in return the UI.

But, since I am getting this data from the server it has a chance to be nil. So by unwrapping with "if let" it creates a copy and that the mutating func no longer updates the UI. Here is my setup for more context.

ProfileViewModel
This is my Profile View Model. I have an enum of states that helps me on the UI side render based on the state.

```
@Observable class ProfileViewModel {
    
    enum State {
        case idle
        case loading
        case failed
        case success
    }
    
    private(set) var state: State = .idle
    private(set) var userProfile: UserProfile? = nil
    
    private let manager: UserManager
        
    init(manager: UserManager) {
        self.manager = manager
    }
    
    func getUserProfile() async {
        guard case .idle = state else {
            return
        }
                
        state = .loading
        
        do {
            let profile = try await manager.getUserProfile()
            state = .success
            userProfile = profile
        } catch {
            state = .failed
        }
    }
    
    func signOut() async -> () {
        do {
            try await manager.signOut()
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    
}
```

ProfileView
This is where my issue really starts. Firstly, if we have a .success case that means we got data back. But I still have to unwrap it and that creates a copy. When I call userProfile.updateUsername() it updates the username of the copy and does not cause a rerender on the UI.

What can I do to solve this or better handle my data? I would like to pass the Model to a child view eventually also.

```
struct ProfileView: View {
    
    @State private var profileViewModel = ProfileViewModel(
        manager: UserManager()
    )
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            switch profileViewModel.state {
                
            case .success:
                if var userProfile = profileViewModel.userProfile {
                    Text("@\(userProfile.username)")
                        .fontDesign(.monospaced)
                    
                    Button {
                        userProfile.updateUsername()
                    } label: {
                        Text("update")
                    }
                }
                
            case .loading:
                ProgressView()
                
            case .failed:
                Text("Sorry, something went wrong.")
                
            default:
                EmptyView()
            }
        }
        .task {
            await profileViewModel.getUserProfile()
        }
    }
}
```

UserProfile

```
struct UserProfile: Decodable {
    private(set) var id: String
    private(set) var username: String
    private(set) var fullName: String?
    private(set) var avatarURL: String?
    private(set) var about: String?
    private(set) var website: String?
    private(set) var joined: String
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case username
        case fullName = "full_name"
        case avatarURL = "avatar_url"
        case about
        case website
        case joined
    }
    
    mutating func updateUsername() {
        username = "justUpdateAndRerenderTheUIPlease"
    }
}
```

I've tried using "if let" and also just checking if the "profileViewModel != nil" but that causes more issues with the optional data.

Comment: One option is to not use a `mutating` function. Put the function on the view model (or even the View). For example: `profileViewModel.userProfile?.username = ""`. Also, you could keep your current code and just replace `userProfile.updateUsername()` with `profileViewModel.userProfile?.updateUsername()`

Comment: when you move to `async/await` you can use `.task { profile = await getProfile(...` then you don't need the class which will make your code less convoluted.

Comment: @malhal Are you referring to the View Model? Getting rid of that?

Comment: @Vik yes .task does that job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhat convoluted way of doing things, but each to their own.

You could try this approach, in your `ProfileViewModel` add

```
 func updateUsername() {
     userProfile?.updateUsername()
 }
```

because you have `private(set) var userProfile: UserProfile? = nil`.

And in `ProfileView` have

```
 if var userProfile = profileViewModel.userProfile {
     Text("@\(userProfile.username)").fontDesign(.monospaced)
     Button {
         profileViewModel.updateUsername() // <--- here
     } label: {
         Text("update")
     }
 }
```

EDIT-1:

you could simplify the code a little, such as:

```
@Observable class ProfileViewModel {
    
    enum State {
        case idle
        case loading
        case failed
        case success
    }
    
    var state: State = .idle      // <--- here
    var userProfile: UserProfile? // <--- here
    
    @ObservationIgnored private let manager: UserManager // <--- here
    
    init(manager: UserManager) {
        self.manager = manager
    }
    
    func getUserProfile() async {
        guard case .idle = state else { return }
        state = .loading
        do {
            userProfile = try await manager.getUserProfile()
            state = .success
        } catch {
            state = .failed
        }
    }
    
    func signOut() async -> () {
        do {
            try await manager.signOut()
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
 
}

// for testing, struct or class whatever
struct UserManager {

    func signOut() async throws { }
    
    func getUserProfile() async throws -> UserProfile? {
        return UserProfile(id: "id-1", username: "user-1", joined: "joined-1")
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ProfileView()
    }
}

struct ProfileView: View {
    
    @State private var profileViewModel = ProfileViewModel(manager: UserManager() )
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            switch profileViewModel.state {
                
            case .success:
                if let userProfile = profileViewModel.userProfile {
                    Text("@\(userProfile.username)").fontDesign(.monospaced)
                    Button {
                        profileViewModel.userProfile?.username = "new username" // <--- here
                    } label: {
                        Text("update")
                    }
                }

            case .loading:
                ProgressView()
                
            case .failed:
                Text("Sorry, something went wrong.")
                
            default:
                EmptyView()
            }
        }
        .task {
            await profileViewModel.getUserProfile()
        }
    }
}

// --- here
struct UserProfile: Decodable {
    let id: String
    var username: String
    var fullName: String?
    var avatarURL: String?
    var about: String?
    var website: String?
    var joined: String
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, username, about, website, joined
        case fullName = "full_name"
        case avatarURL = "avatar_url"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing that, I'll give it a shot now! Do you mind sharing some thoughts on how I could make it less convoluted and "clean" overall? Cheers.

Comment: Worked like a charm thank you. One follow up I have is, the child view of Profile is the Settings screen. The Settings screen needs this user profile also to just show what the current user info is before updating. I could pass the user profile no problem but that would not give me access to the methods in the view model for updating now. Would passing the instance of the view model to the settings screen be acceptable or is there a better way?

Comment: Updated my answer with more code. 
 Have a look at this  **official** link, it gives you some good examples of how to manage data in your app:
 [Managing model data in your app](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app).
This will show you how to pass the `ProfileViewModel` to all views where you can then access its `userProfile`

Comment: Thank you that helps a ton! I’ll make those changes and take note of them moving forward.